# Driving a bitslice of a virtual interface signal through a task

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm trying to create a task that's responsible for setting a bit of a vector and clearing it after one clock cycle. My driver code is attached below:

```
class my_if_driver extends uvm_driver;
  `uvm_component_utils(my_if_driver)
 
  // Members
  // UVM stuff
  virtual my_if_interface vif;
 
  function new(string name="my_if_driver", uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name, parent);
  endfunction
 
  extern function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
  extern function void connect_phase(uvm_phase phase);
  extern task          run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
 
  extern task drive_my_if(my_if_transaction txn);
  extern task set_then_clear(ref logic signal);
endclass
 
function void my_if_driver::build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
endfunction
 
function void my_if_driver::connect_phase(uvm_phase phase);
endfunction
 
task my_if_driver::run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
  @(posedge vif.resetn);
  forever begin
    seq_item_port.get_next_item(req);
    fork
      drive_my_if(req);
    join_none
    seq_item_port.item_done(req);
  end
endtask

// NOTE: each 'command-signal' has bit for each tid (transaction ID)
task my_if_driver::drive_my_if(my_if_transaction txn);
  // Wait for delay
  repeat (txn.cycle_delay) @(posedge vif.clk);
  // Then drive appropriate signal
  if (txn.my_if_cmd == my_if_transaction::CMDA) begin
    set_then_clear(vif.my_if_cmd_a[txn.tid]);
  end
  else if (txn.my_if_cmd == my_if_transaction::CMDB) begin
    set_then_clear(vif.my_if_cmd_b[txn.tid]);
  end
  else if (txn.my_if_cmd == my_if_transaction::CMDC) begin
    set_then_clear(vif.my_if_cmd_c[txn.tid]);
  end
endtask
 
task my_if_driver::set_then_clear(ref logic signal);
  signal <= 1'b1;
  @(posedge vif.clk);
  signal <= 1'b0;
endtask
```

I get the following errors (Questa 10.6) :

> ** Error: path_to_driver.svh(53): LHS in non-blocking assignment may not be an automatic variable
>
> ** Error: path_to_driver.svh(55): LHS in non-blocking assignment may not be an automatic variable

These point to the non-blocking assignments to 'signal' in the set_then_clear task. Is there a way to point to a bitslice of a virtual interface via a ref argument?

Comment: Try changing the non-blocking assignment on those two lines to blocking. I did try your code on EDAplayground and got another error "Object 'this.vif.my_if_cmd_a[txn.tid]' cannot be passed by reference. Allowed object types include variables, class properties, unpacked structure members, and unpacked array elements." (I haven't checked if this error is an simulator issue or an SV rule.)

Comment: Based on Dave's answer, it is an LRM rule (section 13.5.2). The reason I chose to do a non-blocking is because I wanted the value to be updated after all monitoring activities (not using a CB at the moment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LRM says

> Because a variable passed by reference may be an automatic variable, a
>   ref argument shall not be used in any context forbidden for automatic
>   variables.

And you cannot pass a bit select of a packed variable by reference, only the whole variable.

There is no easy way to do this without writing separate tasks for each cmd, or a big case statement inside a signal task that selects the interface variable you want to assign.

Comment: Thanks Dave! I saw this in the LRM, but then I also saw this [thread](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/uvm/lhs-non-blocking-assignment-may-not-be-automatic-variable) where I interpreted your answer as it's possible, so I was hopeful :)
I'll go with the 'big case/multi-if' route.